# Why Backbone view.collection is 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Chat = Backbone.Model.extend({
  messageList: new MessageList(),
  messageListView: new MessageListView({collection: this.messageList}),

 switchChannel: function(channel) {
     this.messageList.fetch({url: 'channels/'+channel, reset: true})
 }
});
```

In other file:

```
var MessageList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Message,
})

var MessageListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log(this.collection)
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
},
```

Why do I gett my collection as 'undefined'?

**console.log(this.collection) -> undefined**

Comment: looks like `this` inside  new MessageListView doesent point to Chat, try like this : var coll = this.messageList; messageListView: new MessageListView({collection: coll})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug:

in

```
var Chat = Backbone.Model.extend({
messageList: new MessageList(),
messageListView: new MessageListView({collection: this.messageList}),
...
```

initialization must be in 'initialize' function

```
var Chat = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.messageList = new MessageList();
    this.messageListView = new MessageListView({collection: this.messageList});
}
```